# Securing only a part of a page

Tags: 6

I am using login box on all pages. Is there a way to secure only the login box part of the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL Certification for securing Login Box which opens the box on https. Add a Login link to your pages and it opens the login box on https.

Comment: its not a thickbox/lightbox to secure only login page its a block and its available on all pages

Comment: you can use Secure Login module. http://drupal.org/project/securelogin